# ccrypt will not decrypt ccrypt-j encrypted files

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, rijndael

I've been trying to fix [`ccrypt-j`](https://github.com/chrsoo/ccrypt-j), a pure-java implementation of the linux [`ccrypt`](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/) command. I found there is some problem with the initialization vector (IV) which makes `ccrypt` not decrypt anything but its own output.

I modified both libraries so that the same nonce is always fed to both implementations of the Rijndael engine, however, the output IV is always different between implementations, i.e. both libraries always have the same result (because Rijndael is deterministic), but those results are always different.

I know the problem is only the way `ccrypt` generates the IV since:

1. ccrypt-j-encrypted can be decrypted from `ccrypt-j`
2. If I substitute the IV (first 32 bytes of the encrypted files) with that of a ccrypt-encrypted file, `ccrypt` will decrypt it just fine.

Ccrypt uses its own implementation of Rijndael coded in C, while ccrypt-j uses Bouncy Castle's implementation.

EDIT: 04/01/2016

Because the IV is constructed before any data is encrypted (actually, any data is even read) I believe the problem has to be in the way Rjindael is initialized in both Bouncy Castle and `ccrypt`'s own implementation. I'll try to do the same sequence in both implementations and see what I get.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Well, you've got the sources for both of them. I'd compare the IV generation part.

Comment: The IV is the result of encrypting the nonce and password with Rijndael. BC's and ccrypt's Rijndaels are totally different implementations and the flows are quite different. That's why I am here. So maybe someone more familiar with Rijndael can help me.

Comment: You'd be better off filing bug reports to both projects.

Answer (score 0):

One half-answer

if you look at the old ccrypt, there are some explanations about IV. if I resume, 4 bytes are fixed - magic number -, it si c051 for a while. Issues about securities are also discussed:

magic number : see that
http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/faq.html

ccrypt comes from emacs / jka-compr:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-51/emacs/lisp/jka-compr.el

> In ccrypt, the seed is constructed as follows: first, a nonce is
> contructed by hashing a combination of the host name, current time,
> process id, and an internal counter into a 28-byte value, using a
> cryptographic hash function. The nonce is combined with a fixed
> four-byte "magic number", and the resulting 32-byte value is encrypted
> by one round of the Rijndael block cipher with the given key. This
> encrypted block is used as the seed and appended to the beginning of
> the ciphertext. The use of the magic number allows ccrypt to detect
> non-matching keys before decryption.

magic number there: http://ccrypt.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.7-7/ccryptlib_8c-source.html

It seems magic number doesnt change (same from 1.1 to 1.10, before, I dont know).

So what ?

ccrypt is designed to be compatible with precedent versions (emacs , ...). It can crypt and decrypt, and is widely used.

Then problem come from ccrypt-j.

what one can see on sourceforge is 2 important things :

**1 compatibility**

> Encrypting a file using ccrypt-j
>
> TODO
>
> Decrypting a file using ccrypt-j
>
> TODO

so what works really ?

2 in fact, it uses bouncy castle, which is well used, and surely implements standards well.

So conclusion ?

you cant hope ccrypt will change.

then: you can decrypt ccrypt by ccrypt-j

but if you want to decrypt by ccrypt, you have to limit ccrypt-j

I doubt about your assertion, because it would be magical !

> If I substitute the IV (first 32 bytes of the encrypted files) with
> that of a ccrypt-encrypted file, ccrypt will decrypt it just fine.

But if it works, why not use that ? (ccrypt-j can also decrypt ?)

last advice: contact ccrypt-j support

hope it helps

Comment: 1. Encrypting a file with ccrypt-j is trivial. They did not fill out those sections in the read.me file, but trust me, it is trivial.
2. Bouncy castle has to be correct. I know. So I guess the implementation of Rijndael in ccrypt is non-standard.
3. My assertion was right provided that the key is always the same.

I don't think there is such thing as ccrypt-j support, it's just someone uploading an implementation of ccrypt to a personal github.